# What is Placing the Blue Sidebar in VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

This is a small and frustrating addition to my VS2013 C# Text Editor.   I only noticed it today so it seems that something I changed is responsible for it.

[image]

and when clicked it displays a text view of the code source:

[image]

I have recently installed [Viasfora](http://viasfora.com/) and updated [VS10x Editor View Enhancer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34eee02b-f1f6-433a-b210-62e94c0bcb87)  But I disabled both and that did not remove it.  I also installed [VSCommands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece)  But removed it almost at once.

Now I am stuck and it seems a dangerous tool to me since the Rollback icon rolls back all the changes I made in one file.  It is too easy to connect to it by mistake so I would like it gone if anyone can tell me what extension is responsible for it.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have Git installed?

Comment: Yes. GitSccProvider.  I just installed that also but did not think that would affect the side bar........

Comment: Try disabling that extension, i bet the bar goes away.

Comment: OK - you are right and my bad for not finding the original question.  Please answer and I will be happy to mark it accepted.  It is the Diff Margin and there is an option to disable it.